# HTML5 Upload via XHR fails in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

I am using XHR to upload a file which works great in FF but fails in Chrome.

An error is thrown which says `Upload failed: 0` which means that xhr.status comes back as `0` - I'm not sure what this means? No other status is recorded.

```
//Check if we have XHR / File support
if (typeof File != "undefined" && typeof (new XMLHttpRequest()).upload != "undefined")
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e){
        if (e.lengthComputable){
            uploadStarted = true;

            var loaded = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;

            ShowProgress(loaded);
        }
    };

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xhr.readyState == 4){

            if (xhr.status == 200){
                uploadComplete();
            } else {
                alert("Upload failed: " + xhr.status);
            }

            console.log("status",xhr.status);
        }
    };

    var formElement = document.getElementById("configForm");

    xhr.open("POST", $("#configForm").attr('action') , true);
    xhr.send(new FormData(formElement));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An `xhr.status == 0` means there was [some network error](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#error-flag). But the specs don't say how you can find out what the error was.

I suggest to log the whole `xhr` structure to the console (`console.log(xhr)`). Maybe one of the other fields contains some valuable data.

If that fails, check the error logs of the server. Maybe something is wrong on the server side.

Comment: Hey thanks for the info.  There is definitely nothing wrong server side, this also fails when using an iframe to post the content so I believe it is something related to Chrome.. or our internal proxy perhaps?